# Message converts argument to string before formatting it

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, message-coding

How to pass automatically, context-dependently formatted arguments to `Message`? Interestingly, `StringForm` correctly interprets the object, but `Message` does not. If possible, I'd rather avoid box-programming. (*Mathematica* 13.3, Win64)

```
ClearAll[Object, ObjectForm];

ObjectForm[Object[a_]] := Style[a["Name"], Darker@Cyan];
Object /: Format[o_Object, StandardForm] := ObjectForm@o;

o = Object@<|"Index" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Name" -> "myObject"|>;
ObjectForm@o (* This displays correctly *)

General::msg = "This object `1` is badly formatted.";
StringForm[General::msg, o] (* This also displays correctly *)
Message[General::msg, o] (* It is converted to string before evaluating the lookup *)
```

[image]

Furthermore, applying `ObjectForm` in `Message` works, but is suboptimal, because replacing all `Object[...]`-s with `ObjectForm[Object[...]]` in the `Message` arguments would be complicated and likely to cause additional errors.

```
Message[General::msg, ObjectForm[o]]
```

[image]